# Date Format conversion to 21st century dates

Tags: java, date, date-format

I have a date in the format `DD/MM/YY` (something like this: `10/12/03`). I want to format it into a different format (i.e. `MM/dd/yyyy`) using the SimpleDateFormat.

When I try this:

```
try {
                // Old Date is 10/12/03
                newDate = simpleDateFormat.format(format.parse(oldDate));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStacktrace();
            }
```

Presently, after formatting the year is coming as `0003` but I want the year to be `2003`. Any inputs on this please?

Comment: Take a look at [`SimpleDateFormat#set2DigitYearStart`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#set2DigitYearStart(java.util.Date))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`SimpleDateFormat#set2DigitYearStart`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#set2DigitYearStart(java.util.Date))

This allows you to define the "base" year for two digit years, for example...

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2000);

SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
inFormat.set2DigitYearStart(cal.getTime());
SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
try {
    // Old Date is 10/12/03
    String value = outFormat.format(inFormat.parse("10/12/03"));
    System.out.println(value);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Will output `12/10/2003`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it helped. I am facing a problem: I have other date as well to format, Is there some to add a check like "After conversion, if the year comes as `0003` i.e. first two digits as integers, then change them to `20` and it will become `2003` ? I can't change the year (suppose `1954` to `2054). Please advice how to place the check for the first two digits of the year.

Comment: If your input is correct (`yy`) then you have no issue, what I might do is check the last series of characters after the last `/` in the incoming `String` to see how many characters there are and adjust the parsing formatter accordingly, so that if `lastCharacters.length() > 2`, use `set2DigitYearStart` otherwise don't, for example...It's better to valid the incoming data, then try and "guess" and the parsed value, IMHO

Comment: Shall I use `CompareTo` for comparing the dates? Or some other options as well? Please advice.

Comment: I don't think `compareTo` in this context will work, you are already making assumptions about two digit years and you'd need to convert the value twice to even get started...

Comment: Ok fine I got it :) Thanks for your inputs.